# Not able to set javascript variable to html. Not getting variable value from html tag

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript file I m calling call categories on page load

```
function call categories(){
      app.request({
        crossOrigin: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "pages/getimage.php",
        data:{},
        dataType: 'json',
        async:true,
        crossDomain:true,
        cache: false,
        success:function( data ) {


        var result = data;
          $.each(result, function(key, value){
            $.each(value, function(k, v){
                if(k === "categoryName"){
                    $("#categorybannername").append(v)
                    //var category=document.getElementById('ctegorybannername').innerHTML;
                 }

                if(k === "categoryImage"){
                    $("#categorybannername").append(v)
                }



                     });        

                     }

           );


  }});                                 


  }

  here
```

I am getting data from ajax call. now I want to set the path of the image dynamically below is code

```
var category= document.getElementById('categorybannername').innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById('image').src = "category/" + category + "/01.jpg";                     
                    console.log(category);    
 here
```

but always get undefined in the console.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="page-content">
        <div>

        <div class="block-title" id="categorybannername"></div>

         <a href="/cakecategory/"><img src="category/" + category + "/01.jpg" id="image" class="lazy lazy-fade-in"/></a>
         <div data-background="category/categorybannername/01.jpg" class="lazy lazy-fade-in"></div>


        </div>

        </div>
```

this is HTML code where I want to use javascript variable category

Comment: can you show HTML code as well?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and PHP code please?

Comment: The comment in your code sample contains `// var category=document.getElementById('ctegorybannername').innerHTML` with a *different element id*. Maybe it is all a typo?

Comment: <div class="page-content">
            <div>
   
   <div class="block-title" id="categorybannername"></div>
     
    <a href="/cakecategory/"><img src="category/" + category + "/01.jpg" id="image" class="lazy lazy-fade-in"/></a>
              
    

   </div>

   </div>
            <!-- Link to another page -->
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: "_always get undefined in the console_" Not possible with the provided code, unless you don't mean the `undefined` `console.log` itself returns ..? There's no `innerHTML` in `#categorybannername`, hence the former is probably what happens here.